# slick-slider css infinite bug animation

Tags: css, slick.js

Help me figure out why when it comes to switching from the last to the first slide and vice versa there is a jump of items. 
There should be the same transition as between the first and second slides.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  $('.js-slider-sphere').slick({
    arrows: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: false,
    speed: 999,
    mobileFirst: true,
    rows: 0,
    infinite: true,
    asNavFor: $('.js-slider-sphere-min')
  });


  $('.js-slider-sphere-min').slick({

    arrows: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    dots: false,
    autoplay: false,
    speed: 1000,
    mobileFirst: true,
    infinite: true,
    rows: 0,
    asNavFor: $('.js-slider-sphere'),
    cssEase: 'linear',
    variableWidth: true,

  });

});
```

```css
.b-sphere__list-big {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.b-sphere__item {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
  height: 518px;
}

.b-sphere__item-min {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.b-sphere__image {
  object-fit: cover;
  font-family: "object-fit: cover;";
  width: 100%;
}

.b-sphere__image--big {
  height: 768px;
}

.b-sphere__image--min {
  width: 279px;
  height: 158px;
  margin-bottom: 33px;
}

.b-sphere__info {
  margin-bottom: 41px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 119px 0 0;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 209px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 113px;
}

.b-container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.b-sphere__list-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 405px;
  bottom: 95px;
  overflow: visible;
}

.b-sphere__next-name {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 170px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

.b-sphere__item-min.slick-slide .b-sphere__image--min {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s linear;
  transition: opacity .2s linear;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
}

.b-sphere__item-min:not(.slick-current) .b-sphere__image--min {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.b-sphere__item-min.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active .b-sphere__image--min {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slick-active .b-sphere__next-name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.b-sphere__item-min.slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active+.b-sphere__item-min .b-sphere__image--min {
  opacity: .9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>

<div class="b-sphere__list-big js-slider-sphere">
  <div class="b-sphere__item"><img class="b-sphere__image b-sphere__image--big js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.ellegirl.ru/th.php?url=0/3911/458e/750@500@3911458e4f173f9e3c266925929dcf68-YmYwZDMwOWZlNg.jpg" alt="" role="presentation">
    <div class="b-sphere__info">
      <div class="b-container">
        <div class="b-sphere__title">Автомобили и мотоциклы1
        </div>
        <div class="b-text-block b-text-block--big b-text-block--sphere roboto-regular">
          <p>Серия многофункциональных защитных нанокерамических покрытий для автомобиля. С Ceramic Pro ваша машина всегда выглядит как новая.</p>
        </div><a class="b-button b-button--sphere b-button--without-arrow" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Подробнее">Подробнее</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-sphere__item"><img class="b-sphere__image b-sphere__image--big js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="" role="presentation">
    <div class="b-sphere__info">
      <div class="b-container">
        <div class="b-sphere__title">Водный транспорт
        </div>
        <div class="b-text-block b-text-block--big b-text-block--sphere roboto-regular">
          <p>Серия многофункциональных защитных нанокерамических покрытий для автомобиля. С Ceramic Pro ваша машина всегда выглядит как новая.</p>
        </div><a class="b-button b-button--sphere b-button--without-arrow" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Подробнее">Подробнее</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-sphere__item"><img class="b-sphere__image b-sphere__image--big js-image-wrapper" src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/kibernetika/23548666/189004/189004_original.jpg" alt="" role="presentation">
    <div class="b-sphere__info">
      <div class="b-container">
        <div class="b-sphere__title">Автомобили и мотоциклы2
        </div>
        <div class="b-text-block b-text-block--big b-text-block--sphere roboto-regular">
          <p>Серия многофункциональных защитных нанокерамических покрытий для автомобиля. С Ceramic Pro ваша машина всегда выглядит как новая.</p>
        </div><a class="b-button b-button--sphere b-button--without-arrow" href="javascript:void(0);" title="Подробнее">Подробнее</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="b-sphere__list-content js-slider-sphere-min">
  <div class="b-sphere__item-min"><img class="b-sphere__image b-sphere__image--min js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.ellegirl.ru/th.php?url=0/3911/458e/750@500@3911458e4f173f9e3c266925929dcf68-YmYwZDMwOWZlNg.jpg" alt="" role="presentation">
    <div class="b-sphere__next-name icon-arrow-button-next">Водный транспорт
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-sphere__item-min"><img class="b-sphere__image b-sphere__image--min js-image-wrapper" src="http://www.factroom.ru/facts/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/122-620x420.jpg" alt="" role="presentation">
    <div class="b-sphere__next-name icon-arrow-button-next">Автомобили и мотоциклы
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="b-sphere__item-min"><img class="b-sphere__image b-sphere__image--min js-image-wrapper" src="http://ic.pics.livejournal.com/kibernetika/23548666/189004/189004_original.jpg" alt="" role="presentation">
    <div class="b-sphere__next-name icon-arrow-button-next">Автомобили и мотоциклы1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to transfer the animation from the parent block to the internal ones, but it did not help, the topics still jump to the left edge of the screen. Examples that did not help.

You can see an example here http://jsfiddle.net/drtvader/of2bjudr/24/